# MySQL - How can I know my query is tuned?

Tags: mysql, performance, explain

I'm creating a DB from scratch and I'm trying to create queries with performance in mind. For test purpose I filled my tables with test data.

My query needs to join 3 tables: 2 with millions of rows and the third with hundred thousands rows.

How can I know my query is the fastest possible?
Here the result of explain:

[image]
From the explain I noticed that the query is using exactly all the Indexes I created for it, so I should be happy and it should be fast, but it's taking 3 seconds (when I execute it after MySQL reboot), and for a real time application this is way too much.

Basically I have two question:

1. Is there a way to "matematically" detect if the query is best performing. i.e. check the number of row scanned
2. How can I test queries speed? I try with "select sql_no_cache ..." or with "FLUSH QUERY CACHE;" or "RESET QUERY CACHE;" between queries, but the result is always that queries seems faster after the first time. I noticed that my query takes long time only the first time after the MySQL reboot (lets say 3 seconds), than also if I change some parameter (and I don't reboot the MySQL) is faster (lets say 0.6 seconds).

Thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for trivial queries, there is no way to know if you have the optimal query & indexes.  Nor can you get a metric for how well designed the schema and application are.

3 seconds on a cold system for a 3-way `JOIN` with "Rows" of 409, 45, 1 is not too bad.  Will 0.3 seconds be ok on a warm system?  Won't the system be running warm most of the time?

The "Query Cache" has one purpose, but it not useful for *most* production systems.  It remembers the output from each SELECT; then if the *identical* query comes along *before* that table(s) changes, it will very rapidly (~1ms) return the saved resultset.  In a typical production system the table(s) is changing too often for this to be useful.

Either turn the QC off (_size=0 and _type=OFF), or use `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE...` when timing queries.

"Using index" is good, but it does not prove anything.  If you would like to discuss that particular query, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `SELECT`.  We *may* be able to suggest better datatypes, better indexes, rearrangement of the schema, reformulation of the `SELECT`, or even a redesign of your application.

I see "geo" -- if you are using latitude and longitude, then there is a non-trivial, non-obvious, but much faster way to "find the nearest", but it involves just about everything I mentioned in the the previous paragraph.

Back to your mathematical question -- *If* you are comparing *two* `SELECTs`, here are two imprecise ways to compare their performance:

- Multiple the `Rows` column (409*45*1) in the `EXPLAIN` for each `SELECT`; see which has the smaller product.
- `FLUSH STATUS; SELECT ...; SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';`; see which `SELECT` has the smaller values.

Comment: Thanks very much! Yes the system will be running warm the whole time, I didn't realized that cold system is slower than a warm one. From my last findings I can say that you could add an important note: in a SELECT you should avoid (if possible) "Using Temporary; Using Filesort" (when running explain). I did it and now that SELECT is taking 0.7 seconds on a cold system.

Comment: A speed-up of 10x is typical between cold and hot -- just because of I/O.  You got about 5x.  Tmp and Filesort are not always avoidable.  There may be more to squeeze out of the query.